# Object doesn't support property or method 'stringify' in IE9 compatible view

Tags: json

I'm using JASON with handler to perform some server side operation. It works find in all browsers except in IE 7 and IE9 Compatible view. I'm using JSON2.js provided by Douglas Crockford. On the execution of following line: 
return JSON.stringify(request);

Error message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'stringify'"